# Trouble converting NSData to int

Tags: ios, int, hex, decimal, nsdata

I have an NSData object that contains just `<64>` which is supposed to represent the int `100`
How can I convert this NSData to an int?

I can convert it to it's `Chr` equivalent `d` using

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but I need the `Dec` equivalent of `100`

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<64>` means that the `NSData` object contains a single byte with the value 0x64 = 100,
so the following should work;

```
const uint8_t *bytes = [data bytes]; // pointer to the bytes in data
int value = bytes[0]; // first byte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *b = (int *)data.bytes;
printf("%d",*b); //prints 100
```

Comment: But the OP's data has a single byte, not 4 bytes.

Comment: but the solution wokrs for single byte also.

Answer (score 0):

Below logic converts NSData to integer perefctly. Length of bytes does not matter. It just works.

```
NSData *data;
NSString *stringData = [data description];
stringData = [stringData substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [stringData length]-2)];

unsigned dataAsInt = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: stringData];
[scanner scanHexInt:& dataAsInt];
```